# TypeError: Cannot read property 'snippet' of undefined

Tags: javascript, api, reactjs, youtube

I have the following two classes. I think the main problem here is that the render function passes the initial states instead of the updated states that are updated with the help of the YTsearch API. If I print the information about videos on console, I do receive the relevant information about the searched query in terms of an Object. But when passing these objects to a new Component (Title) it seems to be undefined (null).

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Component } from 'react';
import Youtube from './Youtube';
import Title from './Title';
import YTSearch from 'youtube-api-search';

const key = '************************************';

class YoutubeVideo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {video:'', selectedVideo:'', received: false};
    this.getvideos();
  }

  getvideos() {
    YTSearch({key: key, term: 'football'}, (videos) => {
        this.setState({
            videos: videos,
            selectedVideo: videos[0],
            received : true
            });
        });
  }

  render() {
        if (this.state.received){
            return (
                <Title videoTitle={ this.state.selectedVideo }/>
            )
        }
        return (
            <div>
            </div>
        )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <YoutubeVideo />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Title.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


class Title extends Component {

    render () {
    const video = this.props.videoTitle;
        return (
            <div>
                <div>{ this.video.snippet }</div>
                <div>{ this.video.snippet }</div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Title;
```

I get the following error in the Title.js:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'snippet' of undefined
```

Please help.

Comment: Instead of defining initial value of `selectedVideo` in state as blank string, define it as blank object, like this: `selectedVideo: {}`, and it should be `{video.snippet}` not `this.video.snippet`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In Title.js, use {video.snippet} not this.video.snippet.
2. you can use react component life cycle methods to call getvideos() method.